# google chrome drag textfield

Tags: google-chrome, resize, textarea, textfield

Im making a website, in one of my pages im using a textarea, but when im look in google chrome i can drag the textarea very big.
is there a way to disable this?

THNX!
Stefan

Answer (score 2):

Add the CSS rule

```
textarea
{
    resize: none;
}
```

Keep in mind that this generally should not be done unless your textarea has its own resize bar (like in Stack Overflow), resizes automatically, or is already very large.